# Change GameObject materials back to Original ones

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a stone skill effect on a gameObject (a skeleton with a spear) changing its materials to a stone one and then changing back to previous ones.

What I'm interested in is the change back. 
The gameObject has some childs and childs of childs.
On some of these childs the are renderers.
Some of these renderers have more than one material attached.

What I ask for is a code to save the materials attached to these renderers and a code to set them again after the stone effect ends....or something similar.

I tried many times but I didn't obtain a complete result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply save the references to the original materials on the start like

```c#
 // Here we store the renderers
private Renderer[] _childRenderers;

// Here we store all materials of each renderer
private readonly Dictionary<Renderer, Material[]> _originalMaterials = new Dictionary<Renderer, Material[]>();

private void Awake()
{
    // Get all Renderer components of this GameObject and any child
    // of it (recursively)
    _childRenderers = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();

    // For each renderer get the original materials
    foreach (var childRenderer in _childRenderers)
    {
        _originalMaterials[childRenderer] = childRenderer.sharedMaterials;
    }
}
```

Now you have all references to the original materials for each `Renderer` stored and can reset them e.g via

```c#
public void ResetMaterials()
{
    foreach (var childRenderer in _childRenderers)
    {
        childRenderer.materials = _originalMaterials[childRenderer];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. When I have time I'll try to implement it and let you know if it works :)

Comment: glad to help :) Please feel free to accept the answer